# Как поменять родителя элемента с помощью css?

Tags: html, css

Нужно блоку `vector-editor-surface-preview__guidlines-checkbox__wrapper` поменять родителя (из класса `vector-editor-modal-content` переместить в класс `vector-editor-modal-footer`), как это можно сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С помощью css - никак, а вот с помощью js можно

Comment: спасибо, думала вдруг можно стилями.

Comment: С помощью стилей есть вероятность что можно элемент визуально переместить, в нужное тебе место... Но не менять ДОМ-дерево.

Comment: как минимум дать элементу "всплыть" в иерархии, хоть и условно но можно. `display: contents` отправляет своих детей к бабушке на лето, а сам драпает в отпуск) или... любой `position: absolute` выдергивается из статичного потока и цепляется за ближайшего позиционированного предка. а вот засунуть в другой контейнер уже врятли выйдет. можно еще на `custom-html-elements` глянуть(который без js не сильно то и функционирует) хм... `checkbox_wraper`... может вам стоит взглянуть на `<select multiple> и <label>`? :3 *а вообще неплохо бы узнать более конкретную цель, дабы знать чего добиваться*